sh: next: command not found on nextJS project, even after re installing node modules
I have just cloned a repo that i was working on from my windows machine, i now have it on my MacOS, i hit npm i and it created the node_modules but when i do npm run dev it gives me this error:
rakibulb@Rakibuls-MacBook-Air advanced-todolist % npm run dev

> todo-enhanced@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

sh: next: command not found

I have looked up solutions online and on stack overflow, most of them said that they just removed node_modules and re-installed, which i tried but it did not work. I have also tried updating my npm version and Node version but nothing seemed to help.
This is my packagage.json :
{
  "name": "todo-enhanced",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.13.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@vercel/postgres": "^0.8.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.378.0",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.4",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^5.13.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

I am also on the same level of my package.json :


The issue here is that i did not have next.js installed globally, so all i had to do was npm i -g nextjs, this made sure i had next.js in my whole device and then it found next.js

That's not right. In fact, you should not install next globally at all. It would make a lot of version conflicts between the globally-installed and next in package.json
